# Did soldiers of Alexander's army settle in Malana?

Tags: history, india, archeology

Malana is an ancient Indian village in the state of Himachal Pradesh.

You can read more in [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malana,_Himachal_Pradesh).

It is believed that the people live there are descendants of Greek soldiers of Alexander's army.

The above claim is mentioned in almost every web page that mentions Malana.

Some examples:

1. [campusdiaries](https://campusdiaries.com/stories/the-real-story-of-malana-village-that-produces-the-best-hash-in-the-world)
2. [kullutourism.com](http://kullutourism.com/)
3. [traveltriangle.com](http://traveltriangle.com/blog/secrets-of-malana/)
4. [scoopwhoop.com](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/inothernews/malana-himachal-pradesh/)
5. [Trawell.in](http://www.trawell.in/himachal/kullu/jamula-temple-malana)

Are there any historical or archaeological studies done on this claim?

Comment: I understand why Skeptics might seem a good choice, but I believe this would be better on our History site.

Comment: @DJClayworth  Okay, then can we migrate this question to History SE.

Answer (score 5):

"The Ethnological and Historical Enigma-The Malanese People of Kulu Valley." The Oriental Anthropologist (2016) vol. 16 :

> It has been emphasized before that though the Greek origin theory of Malanis mentioned above caters only to popular appeal, with a few words of 'Kanashi', physical features of the people and the bicameral political structure present in Malana appearing to be of Greek provenance, recent genetic-typing of the Malani population is more consistent with an Indo-Aryan origin.

See also [The Most Ancient Democracy in the World is a Genetic Isolate: An Autosomal and Y-Chromosome Study of the Hermit Village of Malana (Himachal Pradesh, India)](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.3378/027.082.0201) *Human Biology* (2010) vol. 2, pages 123-141